# Comparator function error in C++ using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am comparing two strings in addition to hamming distance from "00000".

```
std::vector<std::string> vecWeaponsRequired;

struct sHammingDistInfo {
        int iHammingDistance;
        int iIndexToWeaponsVector;
};

bool bWeaponStringComparision(std::string strLevel1Weapon, std::string strLevel2Weapon) {

    bool bFirstLevelStringLessThanSecond = false;

    for (unsigned int iIdx = 0; iIdx < strLevel1Weapon.length(); iIdx++) {
        if(strLevel1Weapon[iIdx] == strLevel2Weapon[iIdx]) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            if(strLevel1Weapon[iIdx] < strLevel2Weapon[iIdx]) {
                bFirstLevelStringLessThanSecond = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return bFirstLevelStringLessThanSecond;


}


bool hammingDistLessThanOperator (sHammingDistInfo& lhs, sHammingDistInfo& rhs) {

    bool isLess = bWeaponStringComparision(vecWeaponsRequired[lhs.iIndexToWeaponsVector], vecWeaponsRequired[rhs.iIndexToWeaponsVector]);
    int iFirstStringLess  = 0;
    int iSecondStringLess = 0;
    if(isLess) {
        iFirstStringLess = 0;
        iSecondStringLess = 1;
    }
    else {
        iFirstStringLess = 1;
        iSecondStringLess = 0;
    }
    return std::tie(lhs.iHammingDistance, iFirstStringLess) < std::tie(rhs.iHammingDistance, iSecondStringLess);
}

// sort vector of hamming distance according to hamming distance.
std::sort(vecOfHammingDistance.begin(), vecOfHammingDistance.end(), hammingDistLessThanOperator);
```

When I ran above code for following strings

```
11100
00111
01110
```

For all above string hamiltion distance is 3 so I want data to be sorted as

```
00111
01110
11100
```

I am getting debug assert which I understand that comparator function is not strict weak ordering. Can any one give clue what is error in my comparator function above defined as `bWeaponStringComparision`?

Comment: How does `bWeaponStringComparision` differ from just calling `<`?  Is there any *imtemtional* difference?  Aha; if one string is longer than the other they disagree!  If this is not intentional, replace with `<` and retest code to simplify problem.  If it is, it is not a proper ordering. Second, the `int` less objects -- wouldn't you get the same ordering with `!isLess, isLess` being passed to first and second `tie` respecitively?

Comment: what's the assert message and what line of your code does it relate to?

Comment: On *what exact input* do you get the assert?  [Mcve].

Comment: VS does checked iterators etc i ndebug node, so the assert may be from there.

Answer (score 3):

Without giving you a fix, to answer the question "can anyone give a clue what is error in my comparator function":

As it stands, for the first two items, you get the first less than the second, and the second less than the first

```
hammingDistLessThanOperator(vecOfHammingDistance[0], vecOfHammingDistance[1])
hammingDistLessThanOperator(vecOfHammingDistance[1], vecOfHammingDistance[0])
```

both being true.

You can't have a less than operator tell you x < y and y < x, if you want strict weak ordering.

That's what the problem is.

In fact, you need [three properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering):

- For all x in S, it is not the case that x < x (irreflexivity).
- For all x, y in S, if x < y then it is not the case that y < x
  (asymmetry).
- For all x, y, z in S, if x < y and y < z then x < z
  (transitivity).

(and strictly speaking a forth that uncomparably items have transitivity too).
Your code breaks the asymmetry (at least).
It's worth adding a small test case for each to flush these things out.

Answer (score 0):

"Unfolding" the `tie` and removing the extra variables gives

```
return isLess 
     ? lhs.iHammingDistance <= rhs.iHammingDistance 
     : lhs.iHammingDistance < rhs.iHammingDistance;
```

where it's a bit clearer that if you give it equal strings the result depends on the order of your arguments.